# React-native: new projects issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In the very beginning, I created the AwesomeProject. Later when I use command 
`react-native init MyProject`, it only created a *package.json* there. Before that, it could create other files, but very slow.

I searched some ways to fix it, now it only create one file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2797) that [has been fixed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3193) (be sure to [update react-native-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli)): the command seems to hang forever nothing seems to be downloaded.

Try using `react-native init MyProject --verbose` to see what's happening and/or keep trying. The issue is not coming from your config.

Comment: I solved this problem. use command "npm install --save [AppName]", "react-native android", "react-native run-android"

Comment: Sure you can install all the dependencies from package.json, as it is generated by the init command. But it doesn't explain, nor fix, the buggy behavior of the command. Have fun with react native !